# C# Intersection of 2 collections based on certain properties

Tags: c#, linq, .net-3.5

I have a `WebItem` object defined as

```
public class WebItem
{
    public string Title;
    public string Url;
    public string RandomProperty1;
    public string RandomProperty2;
    public string RandomProperty3;
}
```

I have two `List`s of `WebItem` objects and I'm trying to figure out if there are objects in `List 1` that are in `List 2`. The catch though is that I would consider it match if at least `Title` and `Url` are the same. I don't care much for what the other properties' values are.

Example:

```
List 1
   1: Title="Dog", Url="/dog.aspx", RandomProperty1="Yorkshire"
   2: Title="Cat", Url="/cat.aspx", RandomProperty1="Persian", RandomProperty2="Grey"
   3: Title="Rat", Url="/rat.aspx"

List 2
   1: Title="Dog", Url="/dog.aspx", RandomProperty1="Pitbull"
   2: Title="Cat", Url="/kitten.aspx", RandomProperty1="Persian", RandomProperty2="Grey"
   3: Title="Bird", Url="/bird.aspx", RandomProperty1="Parrot"
```

In this case, the only 'match' would be "Dog" since the `Title` and the `Url` is the same.

How would I do this in Linq? I thought about using `.Intersect` but that I'm not sure about the conditions regarding the properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just implement `IEqualityComparer<T>` for your class (e.g. GetHashcode and Equals), then use Intersect.

An example of implementing Equals method would be:

```
public bool Equals(WebItem x, WebItem y)
{
    return x.Title == y.Title && x.Url == y.Url;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could provide your own override of `GetHashCode` and `Equals` if you truly intend that in all cases, two items are equal if the two properties are equal. If this isn't the case and you only want equality to work this way for the purposes of this one operation, use linq `Intersect` but use a [different overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb355408(v=vs.100).aspx) and provide your own `IEqualityComparer<T>`.

Comment: Oh, didn't realize that `Intersect` can take an overload. Thanks!